# jquery iterate through list elements

Tags: jquery

say you have this html

```
<ul class="nav sub_nav_home">
    <li id="sub_nav_home1"><a href="#"><span>LINK1</span></a></li>
    <li id="sub_nav_home2"><a href="#"><span>LINK2</span></a></li>
    <li id="sub_nav_home3"><a href="#"><span>LINK3</span></a></li>
 </ul>
```

how do you iterate through each "li" in jquery adding a class "current", waiting for 3 seconds and then moving onto the next "li, and once you get to the end start again?

Thanks

Comment: define 'start again': at the end of the iteration you want add the same class again? or you want to toggle that class?

Comment: I want it to start again at the first "li" and keep looping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution might look like this:

```
$(function() {
  var nav = $("ul.sub_nav_home");
  setInterval(function() {
    var next = nav.find("li.current + li, li:first-child").last();
    nav.find("li.current").removeClass("current");
    next.addClass("current");
  }, 3000);
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bTzv2/4/).  You can compact this down a bit more, just trying to clearly lay out what's going on.  What this does is run the executed function every 3 seconds, we find the `<ul>` from the start to cache things, then on each run we get the one after the `.current` `<li>` (if there is one) and the first, in case we're at the end.  We take the last of those (since they're in document order), so we always prefer the next one over looping back to the start.  Then just remove the class from the current one and add it to the next in line.

Comment: yeah that seems to do the trick  - thanks. How would you do to stop from running that function everytime you hover the mouse over the list? and to continue again once you hover out?

Comment: @user - You could store the interval ID it's creating, like this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bTzv2/6/ (I lowered the interval just for display purposes).

Comment: @user - intervals fire after the first second, if you just hover in the area it works, here's a version with a border added to make it clearer: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bTzv2/7/

Comment: it's actually doing the opposite of what I was asking : ) that script makes the current class rotate only on hover. What I asked was that it should always rotate until we hover over the list

Comment: @user - oo, gotcha, yeah just reverse it and trigger the `mouseleave` handler to kick it off initially, like this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bTzv2/8/

Comment: awesome : ) one last thing. I'mtrying to add a fadein/fadeout effect but it makes the link dissapear completely for some reason...

Comment: @user - you keep changing the question...you should ask the question you're intending to ask, otherwise this becomes almost useless for other users later...which is the entire point of StackOverflow :)

Comment: yeah sorry, I guess I just kept adding things to the original question... should I just create a new question then?

Comment: @user - I would, it's a much more useful resource for others if it stays on topic

Answer (score 1):

you can use each function

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this...
`jQuery('#nav sub_nav_home li').each()`